# How to fix Error 403 when parsing a site on python?

Tags: python, parsing

When trying to parse webpage's response i get an error - `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`. How i can fix this?

Code:

```
import urllib.request
from lxml.html import fromstring

response = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.hltv.org/player/7998/s1mple").read()
page = fromstring(response) 
nameSite = page.xpath('//*[@id="infoBox"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span') 
print(nameSite[0].text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override te user agent:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3'}
reg_url = "https://www.hltv.org/player/7998/s1mple"
req = Request(url=reg_url, headers=headers) 
html = urlopen(req).read() 
print(html)
```

that should do the trick.